# Minecraft command block targeting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I select multiple targets with one command block without using @e[type=!player]?
For instance: 
/execute @e[type=creeper] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=spider] ~ ~ ~ execute....
Does this make the command block only execute the next execute command if the previous entity is found?

Comment: What Minecraft version?

Comment: Minecraft 1.12.2

Answer (score 1):

## 1.13 answer:

Selector arguments are `and` connected, meaning `@e[type=creeper,type=spider]` selects everything that is both a creeper and a spider (which is nothing).

Chaining just splits up the execution, so `execute as @e[type=creeper] as @e[type=spider]` does something as every creeper as every spider, meaning every creeper does it as many times as there are spiders loaded.

What you want is an `or` connection. Minecraft isn't a proper programming language, so you need to repeat your commands for every mob type:

```
/execute as @e[type=creeper] run <command>
/execute as @e[type=spider] run <command>
```

Tip: If you have to do this multiple times or your command is very long, tag them:

```
/tag @e[type=creeper] add spookyScary
/tag @e[type=spider] add spookyScary
/execute as @e[tag=spookyScary] run <command>
/tag @e remove spookyScary
```

---

## 1.12 answer:

Selector arguments are `and` connected, meaning `@e[type=creeper,type=spider]` would select everything that is both a creeper and a spider (which is nothing). In actuality, the command just fails if you enter two of the same selector argument in 1.12.

Chaining just splits up the execution, so `execute @e[type=creeper] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=spider] ~ ~ ~` does something as every creeper as every spider, meaning every creeper does it as many times as there are spiders loaded.

What you want is an `or` connection. Minecraft isn't a proper programming language, so you need to repeat your commands for every mob type:

```
/execute @e[type=creeper] ~ ~ ~ <command>
/execute @e[type=spider] ~ ~ ~ <command>
```

Tip: If you have to do this multiple times or your command is very long, tag them:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=creeper] add spookyScary
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=spider] add spookyScary
/execute @e[tag=spookyScary] ~ ~ ~ <command>
/scoreboard players tag @e remove spookyScary
```

Comment: Note to self: `*` doesn't work in `/tag`, don't try to optimise away the `@e`. ;)

Comment: I didn't forgot to change it. I have a pretty old laptop which can only run minecraft properly with optifine, but there is no optifine for 1.13+ versions.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, 1.13 performance is pretty bad. Even on my pretty good laptop I struggle to get 60fps sometimes. Do you also want a 1.12 answer? It's the same principle.

Comment: Yes please. (Don't come with a struggle for 60fps to me, I'm struggling for 60 fps with optifine and all settings on fast or off)

Comment: Yes please (I don't know if you received my comment, because I can't see it anywhere myself so I'll answer again).... oh. There it is. Never mind.

Comment: I'll try using tags anyway, even though it may not work in 1.12.2. I noticed that my machine has become very big. I got 4 command blocks for each overworld hostile mob and snowballs (just for the fun of it). The first block uses /execute @e[type='mobname'] ~ ~ ~ particle portal 'rest of the command'

Comment: Added the 1.12 answer. Differences: Two times `type` fails completely in 1.12, using the old `execute <selector> <coordinates>` syntax and the old `scoreboard players tag <selector> (add|remove) <tag>` syntax.

Comment: After a overcomplicated delay set up a lightning bolt is summoned with repeating and needs redstone and after another shorter delay other particles like lava are being summoned. With the tag command I can bring it down to just 1 command block for each step instead of 10 blocks each step XD.

Comment: Thanks. I never understood the scoreboard command (I have played minecraft for years, but never used commands except for /time and difficulty), but I think I can figure it out by myself (and youtube).

Comment: The wiki is your friend: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard Basically you write numbers to a score of a person (or entity) and then you can check it later or display it. For scoreboards, you can do a lot more, but tags are easier: Add to someone, remove from someone, check if someone has it (or execute for everyone with it).